# getting Host key verification failed for git clone https://... url

Tags: docker, github, jenkins

I am running

```
git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3.git
```

This gives and error message of

```
Cloning into 'chisel3'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.4' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The command has worked in the past(It is a Part of Jenkins running in docker), and started failing a few min back.

why is my `https` url getting converted into a `git@` url?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands on your terminal and then try to clone the repo

```
echo "Host *" > ~/.ssh/config
echo " StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: Did not work.

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
 StrictHostKeyChecking no


jenkins@cb102f7576cb:/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3.git
Cloning into 'chisel3'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```